# Parse 3 level Nested Json Objects in Retrofit 2

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

Can someone please help me parse this below response as I'm unable to do it, any help is much appreciated! I've checked many links on SO but none seems to be helpful or I've been unable to understand as I'm new to retrofit!

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "description": "Successfully Login",
    "token": "xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxy",
    "details": {
        "userid": "",
        "name": "",
        "email": "",
        "contact": "9888888886",
        "usertype": "",
        "parent_id": "",
        "lender_id": "",
        "firstlogin": "",
        "assigned_sales_user": null,
        "user_sub_type": "",
        "status": "active",
        "white_label_id": "",
        "source": "",
        "document": {
            "0": {
                "doc_id": "",
                "user_id": "",
                "doc_name": "",
                "uploaded_doc_name": "",
                "analysis_id": "",
                "current_status": {
                    "status": "xyxyxyxyxy",
                    "file": ""
                }
            },
            "1": {
                "doc_id": "",
                "user_id": "",
                "doc_name": "",
                "uploaded_doc_name": "",
                "analysis_id": "",
                "current_status": {
                    "status": "",
                    "file": ""
                }
            },
            "2": {
                "doc_id": "",
                "user_id": "",
                "doc_name": "",
                "uploaded_doc_name": "",
                "analysis_id": "",
                "current_status": {
                    "status": "",
                    "file": ""
                }
            },
            "3": {
                "doc_id": "",
                "user_id": "",
                "doc_name": "",
                "uploaded_doc_name": "",
                "analysis_id": "",
                "current_status": {
                    "status": "",
                    "file": ""
                }
            },
            "4": {
                "doc_id": "",
                "user_id": "",
                "doc_name": "",
                "uploaded_doc_name": "",
                "analysis_id": "",
                "current_status": {
                    "status": "",
                    "file": ""
                }
            },
            "5": {
                "doc_id": "",
                "user_id": "",
                "doc_name": "",
                "uploaded_doc_name": "",
                "analysis_id": "",
                "current_status": {
                    "status": "",
                    "file": ""
                }
            },
            "6": {
                "doc_id": "",
                "user_id": "",
                "doc_name": "",
                "uploaded_doc_name": "",
                "analysis_id": "",
                "current_status": {
                    "status": "",
                    "file": ""
                }
            },
            "7": {
                "doc_id": "",
                "user_id": "",
                "doc_name": "",
                "uploaded_doc_name": "",
                "analysis_id": "",
                "current_status": {
                    "status": "",
                    "file": ""
                }
            },
            "8": {
                "doc_id": "",
                "user_id": "",
                "doc_name": "",
                "uploaded_doc_name": "",
                "analysis_id": "",
                "current_status": {
                    "status": "",
                    "file": ""
                }
            },
            "9": {
                "doc_id": "",
                "user_id": "",
                "doc_name": "",
                "uploaded_doc_name": "",
                "analysis_id": "",
                "current_status": {
                    "status": "",
                    "file": ""
                }
            },
            "total_records": ""
        }
    },
    "DES_CODE": ""
}
```

Following is what http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ is showing me which is outrageous and not efficient

Comment: There is a thing called Json Array too. Why that is not used in the json structure ?

Comment: @VivekMishra Thanks for your time and I know about JSONArray too but my backend developer has given me this so have to make do with this..

Comment: Don't agree to wrong things and waste your time in solving issues that can be done easily on backend side

Comment: Thanks for the support will ask him to change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because structure of json is kind of stupid, instread of just use list, you should use map

So it will be like this

```
public class Details {
   @SerializedName("document")
   @Expose
   private HashMap<Integer, DocumentModel>

   //Some fileds
}

public class DocumentModel{
   //Some fileds
}
```

Comment: I have tried the above but it's giving me this error FAILED: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 20 column 2 path $.details.document and I know have to use Gson builder as a client but I doubt that would solve the problem as the JSON itself is weird

Comment: the problem was with "total_records": "40" which need to be out of the document object